# Comments don't count characters correctly

Tags: bug, comments

Try adding a comment with spaces in it.  Note as you type the spaces, the `X more to go...`.  counter goes down.  An example is the following:

```
123          456
```

Each space decrements the counter, and eventually breaks into the "X characters left".  You can get all the way down to "0 characters left".  With only one or two nonwhitespace characters entered.  It's possible to have "0 characters left" and still get the error shown below.

[image: adding comment bug demo]

Comment: 123........456?

Comment: 123456 `catch CommentTooShortException e`

Comment: another status-bydesign

Comment: Little known fact, SO developers are huge fans of Fortran and [consider spaces irrelevant](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Beginning_Fortran#Spaces).

Comment: Little known fact: bananas pad twice as much.

Answer (score 1):

*Think about this*, why would it be appropriate for a user to be able to comment with **just** whitespace? It doesn't make any sense to not validate it for whitespace.

We don't want white space replies, or very *very* short replies, padded out with spaces to pass validation. Hence, you can't reply with blocks of whitespace.

It's not wrong in saying there's less than 15 chars. 123.456, is 7 chars as far as the validator sees it.

Basically:

1. We don't want < 15 char comments padded out with whitespace to pass through, so we check for it.
2. When it validates it, it reads your answer as "123 456", not "123       456"

Just to back this up, even if you just type out 123.......456, it shortens it to one space.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​