# Bananas in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279011/what-should-intmax-t-be-on-platform-with-64-bit-long-int-and-long-long-int), I'm seeing *bananas* in two of the comments:

[image]

Am I going bananas?

Comment: It's a Unicode character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/index.htm

Comment: I see our robot has done well.

Comment: @Mysticial: is this robot, perchance, a monkey?

Comment: It's pretty stupid actually. I flag the comments. It would be nice if those putting worthless characters in the field actually provided a constructive comment.

Comment: Op success world dominated

Comment: What's stupid is that minimum character limit

Comment: This sort of monkey business is not at all appeeling.

Comment: Is that a banana in your comment, or are you...

Comment: btw did you know that bananas are radioactive

Comment: @0A0D Careful, the first comment answers the question - correctly.

Comment:  +  =  ! 

Comment: @DanielFischer: Come again?

Comment: @0A0D A comment correctly answering the question is constructive, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is.

Comment: @DanielFischer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

It's noise and before anyone says that its just my opinion, every one of those that I have flagged get deleted. They are also not constructive. Something like, "Yes, that was fixed in C# 3.0. What do you not understand about the API changes?", is better than "Yes <crap characters>"

Comment: @DanielFischer: *Any* comment which abuses Unicode characters to get past the minimum length is, by definition, not constructive IMO*. (*Except on Meta, of course)

Comment: @animuson But _why_ is there a minimum length?

Comment: @animuson What do you mean by "Unicode characters"?

Comment: Constructiveness is not a function of length

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Everything but the ASCII subset, of course.

Comment: @0A0D No that's longer not better

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10509/139168 ... nearly 4 years later, we are still having the same conversation?

Comment: @0A0D To be fair, "Yes, that was fixed in C# 3.0. What do you not understand about the API changes?" is less constructive than "Yes." because the former is provocative and flame bait.

Comment: @Mysticial: Alright, fair enough. I was trying to come up with a substantial hypothetical example, point is Yes is just as useless. If you don't want to provide an answer and just troll people, simply stop responding then. There's a reason people come to SO and it's not to be trolled. We want a quality site.. I am sure you know that by now.

Comment: @0A0D I'm sorry I forgot that metabeings of pure law and order have passed their judgement already and the issue is closed forever (fyi it's still dumb as hell :cripes:)

Comment: I will take offense to "If you don't want to provide an answer and just *troll people*".

Comment: "Yes." was clearly a constructive comment: the asker responded with "thx.". Bananas offered, bananas accepted.

Comment: Hmm

Comment: [The bananas are gone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes!_We_Have_No_Bananas).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Those are instances of [U+1F34C ʙᴀɴᴀɴᴀ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/index.htm). I use them as a filler in comments. I used to use [U+2063 ɪɴᴠɪsɪʙʟᴇ sᴇᴘᴀʀᴀᴛᴏʀ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm), but since some people complained they were seeing the *invisible* separators as squares, I switched to bananas. They also have the advantage of being represented in UTF-16 as surrogate pairs, and thus each counts as 2 for the 15-char limit.

They look like this on my system (Windows 7, Firefox):

[image]

Mac OS ships with some fonts with Apple extensions to OpenType that allow the use of colours in glyphs, and that's why you see them flashy like that.

Comment: And the moral is that SO is bad at counting length of Unicode strings

Comment: I still see squares, and **please don't do that**.

Comment: @animuson Get better browser and better fonts

Comment: Bananas are great and healthy. I think this sends a good message to the SO community in general.

Comment: I see the bananas as squares on Chrome/OS X. I want to see these bananas!

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Chrome doesn't do font fallback (yes, it's that bad).

Comment: Yay for bananas!

Comment: 'tis short[.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: ^^ you see, I don't need bananas to make short comments ;)

Comment: [Yep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170137/comments-dont-count-characters-correctly/170139#comment502996_170139)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!!

Comment: Integers are not that exciting

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSS

Comment: YEAAAAAAAAAHHHH

Comment: Yes, and 15 chars.

Comment: Yes (also you suck)

Comment: Yes, it is. (filler)

Comment: Use ZWSP.​​​​​​

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana,_Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo

Comment: ZWSP does not have carbohydrates.

Comment: At least user zero width space, it has broader support

Comment: @tohecz your "solutions" suck moar than bananas. It makes users try to clean their screen

Comment: @PeeHaa But only on SO and MSO and the sites with this design. On most sites, there's no ugly dotted underlining :/

Comment: ‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Quite right: they do not count Unicode characters at all. They only count old-fashioned 16-bit code ***units***. It’s a known bug.

Comment: @BenBrocka: `s/user/use a/` ??!

Answer (score 31):

It's shorthand for "flag this comment as noise so that it can be removed".

The banana itself is a reference to [a famous theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem).

Comment: Wouldn't  be more apt?

Comment: No

Comment: Does that apply to [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386292/8828658) as well?